# If $ka_k \rightarrow 0$, then $\sum a_k$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I prove the above claim, or find a counterexample? Any hints are greatly appreciated

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3470432/42969

Comment: Thank you Martin